# How do I change a generatedMesh into a custom object from a .obj-file?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, realitykit

I'm trying to create a application to place items in a room with AR using Swift. It already works to place a rectangle in the room. However, I want to replace this rectangle with a custom 3D object taken from an .obj file.

I started from this project: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/content_anchors/tracking_geographic_locations_in_ar

The rectangle is created in the following code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCkRo.png)

I tried several things but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use Reality Converter to change the obj file into a USDZ, then bundled that USDZ with your app so you can import it to RealityKit. Finally set the imported entity as a child of the entity you're placing in the room.